# Deserialize JSON String in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, web

Is there is any other way deserialize JSON string,rather than using the Newtonsoft library? I've a string like

```
string json = "{status : '1',message : '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Description</th><th>Reference</th>  <th>Code</th><th>Dept Code</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th></tr>'}";
```

if i want to access the message property in code behind file, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create class

   ```
    public class TestM
       {
           public string status { get; set; }
           public string message { get; set; }
       }
   ```
2. Than use this in your code

   ```
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    TestM t =  ser.Deserialize<TestM>("{status : '1',message : '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Description</th><th>Reference</th>  <th>Code</th><th>Dept Code</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th></tr>'}");
   ```

Comment: thanks for your reply it is possible to use anonymous object.

Comment: var TestM = new { status = string.Empty, message = string.Empty };

Comment: anonymous object.. i am not quite sure

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).  Deserialize it as a class with what you want to extract, e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which namespace do i need to use for that?thanks for your prompt answer

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer is in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.
DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute are in System.Runtime.Serialization.  The Message class can be in the namespace of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

You need this required namespaces:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Consider this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
   public int status { get; set; }
   public string message { get; set; }
}
```

[`SerializableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) is required to work with [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

USAGE

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

// Deserialize

Foo foo = serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(json);

//now you have access to...

var status = foo.status;
var message = foo.message;
```

You may also deserialize with `JavaScriptSerializer` in a `Dictionary`. See this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> ds = serializer .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

var status = ds["status"].ToString();
var message = ds["message"].ToString();
```

Comment: Which namespace do i need to call for this. thanks for your reply

Comment: Added namespace on the answer, please check

Comment: i got an error when passing a table data as message property.

Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (37): {status : 1 , message : '<table id='excelDoc'><tr><th>Date</th><th>Description</th><th>Reference</th><th>Nominal Code</th><th>Dept Code</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th></tr><tr><td>21/11/2011</td><td>Nov depreciation </td><td>Dep jnl</td><td></td><td></td><td class='db'></td><td class='cr'></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1150</td><td>100</td><td class='db'>0.00</td><td class='cr'>50.00</td></tr></table>'}

Comment: You can't use `'` within a string, it must be escaped with `\'`