# ASP.net: pass dynamically created (by client-side javascript) value along with postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback

I have a button that performs a postback as follows:

*default.aspx*

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="print" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Default.aspx" OnClick="ExportTaxInfoToPDF">Print</asp:LinkButton>
```

*default.aspx.cs*

```
protected void ExportTaxInfoToPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
```

I want to pass a javascript computed value to the codebehind (such as `$('#taxTable').html()` i.e. I want to bind the value of that computation to `EventArgs e` so I can retrieve it on the server side) How could I go about doing that or is there a better way of achieving that?

Thank you

EDIT:

Following Tetsuya Yamamoto's suggestions, I now have the following code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TaxTableData" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="PrintButton" CssClass="print" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Default.aspx" OnClick="ExportTaxInfoToPDF">Print</asp:LinkButton>
```

TaxTableData is populated whenever the popup containing the data (in table format) is opened using directly the HTML of the table:

```
$("#ctl00_maincontent_TaxTableData").val($table[0].outerHTML);
```

The HTML is then converted into PDF using *iTextSharp*. It is a simple html `<table>`:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>...</th>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
..
```

I am wondering if there are better ways of transmitting the data to the server side such as not to be forced to disable security checks? Is there a way to serialize the table and unserialize it on the other side?

Comment: You can use hidden field (either vanilla HTML `input type="hidden"` or `asp:HiddenField` server control) and use `Request.Form["taxTable"]` (or `ClientID` if server control being used) to retrieve the client-side value.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Although, I am getting an error while trying to pass HTML as I need to do (*A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client*) Do you know what would be the best way to pass HTML?

Comment: Try using `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` with `<pages validateRequest="false" />` in web config and `<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" %>` in ASPX page. Which character triggered `Request.Form` error?

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked. It was the `<` character I presume (error message said: `<table style="...`). It is probably a bad idea to pass html in the first place, but disabling this check will do for now.

Comment: I preferred to convert HTML markup into other format (e.g. JSON) before pass it into code behind to prevent `Request.Form` error, then serialize received data in process logic and render the result thereafter. You can edit the question to provide data format you want to pass with, and I can provide steps to do so in detailed answer.

Comment: I have edited the original question as I am interested to know a better way of doing this. You can provide a full answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to pass JS values into code behind on postback, you can set hidden field server control value using this:

```
<!-- ASPX markup -->
<asp:HiddenField ID="TaxTableData" runat="server" Value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= TaxTableData.ClientID %>').val($table[0].outerHTML); // set hidden field value with table markup
</script>

// Code behind
protected void ExportTaxInfoToPDF(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var table = this.TaxTableData.Value; // get passed data
    ...
}
```

Given the passed string from client-side contains HTML table markups, it is possible to throw potential dangerous `Request.Form` exception during postback from the hidden field due to presence of illegal characters. To avoid it, you may try one of the solutions below:

**A. Disable request validation**

Add these lines in `web.config` file:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

Also, in `Page` directive you need to add `ValidateRequest` attribute:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="False" %>
```

This way allows illegal characters included in HTML markup to be passed smoothly, however it can pose security-related issues.

**B. Using JSON serialization**

The HTML markups can be serialized into JSON format using this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= TaxTableData.ClientID %>').val(JSON.stringify({ html: $table[0].outerHTML }));
</script>
```

Then, pass it into code behind using hidden field value and use `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize it, either using dedicated class or a `Dictionary` type:

```
// Code behind
protected void ExportTaxInfoToPDF(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var serializedTable = this.TaxTableData.Value; // get passed data

    // use either dedicated class with SerializableAttribute or Dictionary type
    // this example uses Dictionary for simple HTML markups
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Dictionary<String, Object> dict = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, Object>>(serializedTable);

    var table = dict["html"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

NB: If submitted HTML markup contains attribute with values inside single or double quote marks (e.g. `<table class='example'>`), [escape all quote marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176024/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string) in client-side before setting hidden field value (usually it done automatically when doing `JSON.stringify`).

The serialization method is preferred if you want to keep request validation settings in place, preventing malicious scripts to be executed in client-side.

Related issues:

1. [Passing values from javascript to code behind in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603256/passing-values-from-javascript-to-code-behind-in-asp-net)
2. [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)
3. [How to pass JSON data to code behind method (not to Webmethod)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113595/how-to-pass-json-data-to-code-behind-method-not-to-webmethod)
4. [Deserialize JSON String in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578498/deserialize-json-string-in-code-behind)